# Scrapy pipeline how to save multiple items in multiple tables in a scrapy pipeline

Tags: scrapy

#### Hello

I am trying to run three spiders at the same time and have the scraped items dumped to three different tables using sqlalchemy connected to postgresql database.
All three tables are created in the database, but only one table actually gets populated when running all three spiders. I know I'm doing something wrong but can't see it.

```
I am using Scrapy to scrape the items. Here is my pipelines code 

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Define your item pipelines here
#
# Don't forget to add your pipeline to the ITEM_PIPELINES setting
# See: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from . models import F_hunter,db_connect, create_f_hunter_table, \
                     L_hunter, create_l_hunter_table, \
                     A_hunter, create_a_hunter_table
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem


###########################################################

class HunterPipelineF(object):
    """ Hunter pipeline for storing scraped items to database"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initalize datatbase connection and sessionmaker.
           Creates f_hunter table
        """
        engine = db_connect()
        create_f_hunter_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        """ Saves items link and summary in database.
        Method is called for every item pipeline component
        """
        

        session = self.Session()
        f  = F_hunter(**item)
        
    
        try:
             session.add(f)
             session.commit()
        except:
             session.rollback()
             raise

        finally:
             session.close()

             return item

##############################################################
class HunterPipelineL(object):
    """ Hunter pipeline for storing scraped items to database"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initalize datatbase connection and sessionmaker.
           Creates f_hunter table
        """
        #super(HunterPipelineL, self).__init__()

        engine = db_connect()
        create_l_hunter_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        """ Saves items link and summary in database.
        Method is called for every item pipeline component
        """


        session = self.Session()
        l  = L_hunter(**item)


        try:
             session.add(l)
             session.commit()
        except:
             session.rollback()
             raise

        finally:
             session.close()

             return item
#############################################################
class HunterPipelineA(object):
    """ Hunter pipeline for storing scraped items to database"""
    def __init__(self):
        """Initalize datatbase connection and sessionmaker.
        Creates a_hunter table
        """
        #super(HunterPipelineA, self).__init__()
        engine = db_connect()
        create_a_hunter_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        """ Saves items link and summary in database.
        Method is called for every item pipeline component
        """


        session = self.Session()
        adobe  = A_hunter(**item)


        try:
             session.add(adobe)
             session.commit()
        except:
             session.rollback()
             raise

        finally:
             session.close()

             return item


#class MainHunterPipeline(HunterPipelineF, HunterPipelineL, HunterPipelineA):
#    def __init__(self):
#        super(MainHunterPipeline, self).__init__()
#        return item

#Myhunter = MainHunterPipeline()

class DuplicatesPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.link = set()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if item['link'] in self.link:
            raise DropItem("Duplicate item found: %s" % item)
        elif item['summary'] in self.link:
            raise DropItem("Dulicate link %s" %item)
        else:
            self.link.add(item['link'])
            return item


#MainHunterPipeline
```

Comment: I would like to populate all three tables with different information depending on the spider.

Comment: Can be closed , Decided to use one instance of class for pipeline to combine into one table.